# uninstalling pip3 on mac

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to get the installation right with python 3, pip and pip3. I am working on a mac and by default. I have Python 2.7.10

```
python -V 

Python 2.7.10
python3 -V 

Python 3.5.1
```

What is the correct order of installation commands to install python3 pip and pip3 so that both pip and pip3 can be linked to python3? 
This what I get when I try to see what versions I already have:

```
$ pip -V
-bash: /usr/local/bin/pip: No such file or directory
$ pip3 -V
pip 7.1.2 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages (python 3.5)
```

I need to get this right so that I can install numpy afterward because now with what I have above this is what I get:

```
$ pip3 install numpy
Collecting numpy
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for numpy
```

Comment: You can't have `pip3` linked to `python2` unless you do something seriously weird. You can have `pip` linked to `pip3` but I don't recommend it. Your `pip3` seems correct (linked to something under python 3.5). Just use `python3` and `pip3` instead of `python` and `pip`, or use `virtualenv -p python3` - inside it `python` and `pip` will refer to `python3` and `pip3`.

Comment: the other weird thing is that on terminal I have python3.5.1 but within the applications, I can't find it!!

Comment: Try [anaconda](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/python). It'll help you keep your machine's python install separate from your working versions. I struggled with the exact same problem you are having until I finally switched. It'll put your working tools in front of your path so `pip` will point to 3.x and the system python will stay untouched.

Comment: You could create an alias for `pip` to just be `pip3`. If you're using bash (default shell for mac terminal), the syntax is `alias pip="pip3"`. You can put that line in your `~/.bashrc` and then source it or open a new terminal for the alias to take effect. Amadan is right, though. You should really be sure you want to do this, it's not expected behavior.

Comment: `pip 7.1.2` seems severly outdated. Try upgrading with `pip3 install --upgrade pip`

Comment: @FlyingTeller  upgrading pip gives me this: `Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages`

Comment: @MattMessersmith still having same issue with installing numpy even after making the alias

Answer (score 0):

I have Solved it. as @keithpjolley suggested. I installed anaconda, launched it, and I used the command:

```
conda install numpy
```

I let it solve the environment. It gave me an older version of numpy at first so I upgraded:

```
conda install numpy=1.13
```

Now everything is working with my code.